# Power Automate - Get DisplayName from People object as text

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, power-automate, microsoft-flow

I'm using a `Get Items` action to fetch a list that includes people as one of the columns. Now I need to get the display name of those people as text to put in another field. I've tried numerous approaches but no matter what angle I come from I can't seem to isolate just the display name. I can get the entire People object, but I can't then break it down and get its properties. Is there an easy way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using **Parse JSON** action? For input to Parse JSON, use the **Person** object retrieved by Get Items action, and for Schema, use the below:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "@@odata.type": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "Claims": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "DisplayName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "Email": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "Picture": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "Department": {},
        "JobTitle": {}
    }
}
```

Once you parse the Person type column, all properties should be available in the dynamic content to use in the subsequent steps.

[image]

[image]